# installing older version of QGIS on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I recently installed the latest version of QGIS (2.0) on my UBUNTU 12.04. But am not very satisfied with it. I would like to uninstall it and reinstall QGIS 1.8 v on Ubuntu. Am unable to do so. It would be great if anybody could help me with this.

thanks

Comment: Can you provide us some more information - issues/errors you get when you try to install 1.8, how are you trying to install 1.8 (from UbuntuGIS repository or build from the source)?

Comment: I tried to install it from UbuntuGIS repository. Are there other possible ways to install an older version QGIS on Ubuntu?

Comment: You are in the wrong place. You should ask this question in **Ask Ubuntu**. This subject is not a GIS theme but rather a **GNU/Linux Ubuntu** issue. You don't have the tools for installing from the sources and someone in **Ask Ubuntu** can tell you how.The process is equivalent for any tar gz file.

Answer (score 3):

The [download folder](http://qgis.org/downloads/) contains binaries of older versions for Windows, and the source code of the older versions.

To use with Ubuntu, you have to compile from source on your own, respecting the dependencies of other packages. This installation process is described in http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/doc/INSTALL.html

Another choice is to set up an older version of ubuntu using a virtual box inside your running Ubuntu. Ubuntugis-unstable still has packages of QGIS 2.4 for saucy, and 2.0 for raring, quantal and lucid.

Comment: What about QGIS 3.x? Still, do we have to compile from source to install older versions?

Comment: They offer an LTR-Version now, but beyond that the answer is still valid. Ubuntugis-stable still has QGIS 2.14 for trusty only, and the main ubuntu repo has 2.8 for xenial and 2.18 for bionic.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the older versions here
http://qgis.org/downloads/

I guess it's a matter of downloading the tar.bz2 and installing.

Also, if you point it out what's wrong with the new version, maybe someone could fix it.

Comment: I had some trouble using using the new version such as some of the plugins could not be downloaded properly. Anyways, I have completely uninstalled the new version and want to get back the version that I'm familiar with. how do you install from the downloaded file?