# Install a specific nightly version of QGIS 3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, ubuntu, qgis-3

Is it possible to install the nightly version of QGIS 3 for a specific date (code version)?

I'm working with QGIS 3 development version which recently has some issues with projections and crashes. I was able to recover a virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.04) in Nov that still works.

Before redoing everything else on the VM, I'd like to ask:

Is it possible to tell `apt-get` to install a specific nightly version (e.g. for Nov. 21)?

Note: I can't go back to stable versions (QGIS 2) now as I have written some new python 3 code that only works under qgis3.

Related:
[installing older version of QGIS on Ubuntu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77230)

Comment: Windows nightly builds are saved weekly at https://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/ , but there seems to be no repo for ubuntu nightly buils in the same way. Debian, Ubuntu and ubuntugis are still at 2.14. You can try to get the files from the working VM installation.